# Mapping continuously differentiable at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential

I am reading Coleman's Calculus on Normed Vector Spaces. He defines what it means for a mapping $f: O \to F$  from an open subset $O$ of a normed vector space $E$ to a normed vector space $F$ to be differentiable at a point $x \in O$. Also, such a mapping is differentiable if it is differentiable at every point in its domain.

He than defines that such a mapping is continuously differentiable (or of class $C^1$) when it is differentiable and its differential mapping $f': O \to \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ is continuous.

He does not define what it means for a mapping to be continuously differentiable at a point (at least I could not find a definition), so I am wondering what such definition would be like. This is what I first thought of:

A mapping $f: O \to F$ is continuously differentiable at a point $x \in O$ if there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $N$ and $f': N \to \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ is continuous at $x$.

My questions are:

1. Is it true that a mapping is differentiable at $x$ if, and only if, it has all partial differentials defined at a neigborhood of $x$ and continuous at $x$ (but not necessarily continuous at a neighborhood of $x$?
2. Is this definition useful in any other way?
3. Is it necessary to have $f$ differentiable at a neighborhood to talk about continuity at $x$? This seemed more intuitive to me but I am not sure this is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the definition you give for continuous differentiability at a point is correct.

1. No, it's not true as written. Since you're dealing with general normed vector spaces, you must be careful with the notion of partial derivatives. Once you suitably modify the statement to account for the general normed vector space setting, the correct statements are the following:

> - If all the partials are continuous at a point $x$ (this already requires existence in a neighborhood), then the function is differentiable at $x$ (proof using mean-value inequality). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3242940/568204) for some details sketched out.
> - as a consequence, we can deduce that if all the partials exist and are continuous on an open set, then the function is itself differentiable on that open set. But in fact, based on the explicit formula for the derivative $Df_a=\sum_{i=1}^n(\partial_if)_a\circ \pi^i$, we can even deduce continuity of $Df$ on the open set.
> - The converse of this second assertion is pretty trivial: if $Df$ exists and is continuous on an open set, then all the partials $\partial_if$ exist and are also continuous on that open set.

2. I'm not really sure how to answer this, except to say this is a useful definition, because it can sometimes make proving things easy (eg proving via a simple induction that if $f,g$ are $C^k$ then so is $f\circ g$... I'm sure there are more situations where this way of thinking of continuous differentiability makes things clearer, but unfortunately I can't think of examples off the top of my head right now).
3. Yes.

Comment: Regarding 1., that is what I meant to write, that $f$ is $C^1$ at $x$ iff all its partal differentials are $C^1$ at $x$. I will take a look at the books you mentioned at the answer you refered to here. If we assume But I want to enfasize this to see if I got it right: in Coleman's book, he proves that if $f$ is $C^1$ at $x$ than its partial differentials are $C^1$ at $x$, but for the converse, he uses that the partial differentials are $C^1$ at a neighborhood of $x$, not just at $x$. Is it true if we only assume continuity of the partial differentials at $x$?

Comment: Both in the book Advanced Calculus by Loomis and Sternberg and in the book Calculus on Normed Vector Spaces by Coleman, they enunciate that the partial differentials are continuous on a neighborhood of the point, not just at the point (Theorem 8.2 of section 3 in Advanced Caculus, Theorem 3.6 in Caculus on Normed Vector Spaces).

Comment: As far as I can see, this is used when we find the estimate that (using the Loomis and Sternberg's notation) $||D F^i_{(\mu,\nu)} - D F^i_{(\alpha,\beta)}|| < \varepsilon$, since this is by continuity of the partial differential at $(\alpha,\beta)$, whinch is a generic point in the neighborhood.

Comment: I still do not understand how can we use only differentiability on a neighborhood and continuity of the differential at the point.

Comment: I believe now I understand it: we can prove that if the partial differentials are defined on a neighborhood of a point and continuous at that point, the mapping is differentiable at that point, but that doesn't imply that it is continuously differentiable at that point.

Comment: This argument of continuity makes sense to me, but then we come back to point (3) of my question: to say $f$ is continuously differentiable at point $x$, doesn't the differential $D f$ has to be defined at a neighborhood of $x$? Is seems that we prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and then, without proving that $f$ is differentiable at a neighborhood of $x$, we also show $D f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos no, re-read what I wrote carefully. I hope you now agree that "continuity of partials at a point (which itself requires existence of partials in a neighborhood) implies differentiability at a point". By repeatedly applying this theorem, we deduce that "continuity of partials on a neighborhood implies differentiability on a neighborhood". Finally, based on the explicit formula for $Df$, we can strengthen this to "continuity of partials in a neighborhood implies $Df$ exists and is continuous on that neighborhood" (and for this last theorem, the converse is trivially true.)

Comment: I agree that "continuity of partials at a point (which itself requires existence of partials in a neighborhood) implies differentiability at a point". I also agree that "continuity of partials on a neighborhood implies differentiability on a neighborhood" and that "continuity of partials in a neighborhood implies  exists and is continuous on that neighborhood".

Comment: So just to settle this question: to prove continuity of $D f$ at $x$, we DO need to have continuity of partial differentials at a neighborhood of $x$, since that's how we prove "continuity of partials on a neighborhood implies differentiability on a neighborhood", which we need to prove, "based on the explicit formula for $D f$", that "continuity of partials in a neighborhood implies $D f$ exists and is continuous on that neighborhood".

Comment: But, of course, from the have continuity of partial differentials at a neighborhood of $x$, we prove not only that $D f$ is continuous at $x$, but on the whole neighborhood.

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos oh yes that's totally right, and now I realized why you're getting so confused. It's because my answer is incorrectly stated (I was thinking the things I wrote in the comments but ended up writing something completely different, my bad). I have deleted some of my comments which may have caused confusion, and only left the one comment which contains the three correct theorems. Apologies for the mixup!

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. When you put it in terms of the "3 theorems" it became vert clear. What mostly happens, as you mentioned, is that most books don't state the most general version of the results. Thank you again.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect this. Hopefully this clears up the confusion. haha and thank you for asking questions! this just shows no one is perfect, and sometimes, even if I mean and think of saying one thing, somehow in the quickness of typing I end up saying something completely different.