# What topology is given to $L(X,Y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, definition, banach-spaces

Let $E,F$ be two finite-dimensional Banach spaces, with $U\subseteq E$ open and $L(E,F)$ the collection of linear maps $E\to F$. In the following excerpt (from Abraham's *Foundations of Mechanics*), the authors speak of a function $U\to L(E,F)$ being continuous, implying there is some topology on $L(E,F)$. **What is such topology?**

Furthermore, **why is the definition below equivalent to the usual definition of $f$ being $C^1$ iff its partial derivatives exist and are continuous on $U$ ?**

[image]

Comment: @BrunoB sorry for having left out the details: the maps are from Banach _finite-dimensional_ spaces, so the maps are continuous; the book is Abraham's _Foundations of Mechanics_.

Comment: @BrunoB I don't understand. The strong topology is not -as far as I can see- mentioned in the post.

Comment: See [Derivative function continuous iff partial derivatives continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3242940/568204), and [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4091092/568204). The idea is to use the mean-value inequality, along with a simple telescoping identity. See the references (Cartan/Loomis-Sternberg) for more details (you can even squeeze out a proof from Spivak’s Calculus on Manifolds).

Comment: oh and if you’re considering only finite-dimensional spaces, then the choice of norm doesn’t matter; all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent (i.e give rise to the same topology). But this result holds more generally, and in that case we should use the operator norm as mentioned below in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By all standard accounts, we should want $\mathscr{L}(X;Y)$ to be the space of **continuous** (i.e. bounded) linear maps $X\to Y$ for normed linear spaces $X,Y$. We topologise this by the metric topology; indeed $\mathscr{L}(X;Y)$ is itself a normed linear space with the norm-metric topology. What's the norm? Well, $\|T\|$ for $T\in\mathscr{L}(X;Y)$ is just the operator norm of $T$, $\|T\|:=\sup_{x\in X\\\|x\|\le1}\|T(x)\|$. This exists since $T$ is by definition continuous/bounded.

This is known as the *strong* topology on $\mathscr{L}(X;Y)$, sometimes. There exist other topologies, e.g. the weak operator topology, but in the context of (Frechet) derivatives we use the *strong* topology.

If for $X=\Bbb R^n,Y=\Bbb R^m$ and $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ you consider $f$ to be $C^1$ iff. all of its partial derivatives exist and are continuous, we can show this is equivalent to $f$ having a continuous derivative $\Bbb R^n\to\mathscr{L}(\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^m)$. <s>This is almost certainly a duplicate but a quick search didn't bring anything up</s> - the rest of the details can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3242940), I'll just explain why $\mathrm{d}_f$ can be viewed as the matrix of partial derivatives (the Jacobian).

Firstly assume $\mathrm{d}_f:\Bbb R^n\to\mathscr{L}(\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^m)$ exists and is continuous. For any $1\le i\le m,1\le j\le n$ and any $x\in\Bbb R^n$, $\mathrm{d}_f(x)$ is a linear map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ and we can express it as a $m\times n$ matrix in the canonical basis. Let $a_{i,j}(x)$ be its $(i,j)$th element. We would like to show that this defines a continuous function $a_{i,j}$ and that it serves as $\partial_j^if(x)$.

I can't see your "$1.3.2$" but it's almost certainly something like this: $$\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)-\mathrm{d}_f(x)(y-x)}{\|y-x\|}=0$$

In particular, taking $y=x+(0,\cdots,0,h,0,\cdots,0)$ as $h\to 0$, where $h$ lives in the $j$th coordinate, we find: $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_1,\cdots,x_j+h,\cdots,x_n)-f(x)-(a_{1,j}(x)\cdot h,\cdots,a_{i,j}(x)\cdot h,\cdots,a_{m,j}(x)\cdot h)}{|h|}=0$$Taking $j$th coordinates tells you exactly that $\partial_i(f_j(x))$ exists and equals $a_{i,j}(x)$ (you can replace $|h|$ with $h$ if the limit equals zero), noting that $|\text{something}|\to0$ iff. $\text{something}\to0$.

It's also a good exercise to check that (the linear operators represented by) $A_k$ tends to $A$ in $\mathscr{L}(\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^m)$ iff. the entries of $A_k$ tend to the entries of $A$ (as a usual limit of a real sequence). Then continuity of $\mathrm{d}_f$ is equivalent to continuity of the partial derivatives (if $\mathrm{d}_f$ actually exists).

Comment: Ok! So no need for the spaces to be finite dimensional (:

Comment: @Sam Yeah, no need at all. The whole point of this definition is to generalise everything to arbitrary (real or complex) linear spaces. We don't even need them to be Banach spaces for this definition to make sense

Comment: One last thing: why is the definition of begin $C^1$ equivalent to the usual one?

Comment: @Sam It would help if I knew what you think the 'usual' definition of $C^1$ is for, say, functions $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is

Comment: It's the one they talked about in the remainder of the question. But I'm surprised it's not done in the book, that sounds like a classic result worth giving the proof, at least an outline?

Comment: @FShrike as explained in the post: a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^1$ iff the partial derivatives $\partial_i f_j$ exist and are continuous.

Comment: @Sam I've said a little about this, see peek-aboo's answer for some more details

Comment: @FShrike I'm slightly confused by the proof in the link: **at no point is the topology of $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ mentioned in the proof**. The couple of things I do understand are that $f$ being differentiable implies existance of its partial derivatives and $df$ being the Jacobian, and that existence and continuity of partial derivatives implies differentiability of $f$.

Comment: @Sam The proof in the link covers: "all partial derivates exist and are continuous implies the derivative exists". My final short paragraph covers where the topology appears. Basically, in finite dimensions you can show that $\mathscr{L}(\Bbb R^n;\Bbb R^m)$'s topology is such that [something] converges to [something else] iff. all of the matrix entries converge. Because the matrix entries are just the partial derivatives, continuity of all of the partial derivatives becomes equivalent to continuity of the derivaitve