# $C^1$-convergence on bounded open sets of a sequence of mollified functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

A sequence of *mollifiers* $(\rho_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is any sequence of functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that
$$
\rho_n \in C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^d), \quad \operatorname{supp} \rho_n \subset \overline{B(0,1 / n)}, \quad \int \rho_n=1, \quad \rho_n \geq 0 \text { on } \mathbb{R}^d,
$$
where $B(x, r)$ denotes an open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$.  I would like to verify a claim at page 202 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*

> **Remark 1**  Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb R^d)$. Then $\rho_n * f \to f$ in $C^1$ on every bounded open set of $\mathbb R^d$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt. Could you please have a check on it?

---

**My attempt** If $f \in C^k (\mathbb R^d)$ and $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_d)$ is a [multi-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation?useskin=vector#Definition_and_basic_properties) of length $|\alpha | = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_d \le k$, then we write
$$
D^\alpha f := D_1^{\alpha_1} D_2^{\alpha_2} \ldots D_d^{\alpha_d}  f 
\quad \text{where} \quad
D_i^{\alpha_i} := \frac{\partial^{\alpha_i}}{\partial x_i^{\alpha_i}}.
$$

We need the following auxiliary results from the same book

> - **Proposition 4.20** Let $f \in C_c^k (\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $k \geq 1$ and let $g \in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1 (\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then $f * g \in C^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and
>   $$
>   D^\alpha(f * g) = (D^\alpha f) * g \quad \forall \alpha \text { with }|\alpha| \leq k .
>   $$
>   In particular, if $f \in C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $g \in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^1 (\mathbb{R}^d)$, then $f * g \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^d)$.
> - **Proposition 4.21** Let $f \in C(\mathbb R^d)$. Then $\rho_n * f \to f$ uniformly on compact sets of $\mathbb R^d$.

Let $f_n := \rho_n * f$. By *Proposition 4.20*, we have $D^1_i f_n = \rho_n * D^1_i f$ for all $i=1, \ldots, d$. We have $f \in C^1(\mathbb R^d)$ [IFF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242905/derivative-function-continuous-iff-partial-derivatives-continuous) $D^1_i f \in C(\mathbb R^d)$ for all $i=1, \ldots, d$. Let $O$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb R^d$. Clearly, $\overline O$ is compact. By *Proposition 4.21*, $\|(f_n-f) 1_{\overline O}\|_{\infty} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ and
$$
\| (D^1_i f_n - D^1_i f) 1_{\overline O}\|_\infty \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
\quad \forall i=1, \ldots, d.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks correct to me.